# Dependent dynamically populated dropdown list Google Sheet

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-sheets, dropdown, google-sheets-api

I would simply like to autopopulate the Point Segment with all the segments linked to a specific Street, when the Street name is inputted. 
When Street name is inputted into column C, Column D should have a dropdown containing only the point segments of that street. 
While I realize this can simply be achieved by creating a filter in the Data tab, I am trying to create a form which does not allow this and therefore need to script it.

This is the Google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QbTqPegE_GLj9V6x5uCNNXAoi0v12Pmaelhc7uaMknE/edit?usp=sharing

I have written this code, however I am having trouble filtering by Street.

```
function setDataValid_(range, sourceRange) {
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, 
true).build();
range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
function onEdit() {
var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();

if (aColumn == 3 && aSheet.getName() == 'Sheet1') {
    var range = aSheet.getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = aSheet.getRange('Sheet1!B2:B5131');
    setDataValid_(range, sourceRange)
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but you should use `requireValueInList` instead of `requireValueInRange`. You were passing `sourceRange`, which is equal to *all* of the point segments.

To accomplish the filtering, you need to look at all of the street values. If the street value matches the selection, then save the adjacent point segment to a separate list. Once you've saved all those point segments, then pass it to `requireValueInList`. To do this, you need to take advantage of [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to get the range values as an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) and [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/A_first_splash#Loops) through it.

I've made a few other modifications:

- In `onEdit`, you should use the an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- Changed your variable names so they would be easier to understand
- Added a check to make sure that the Street cell isn't blank (no need to trigger the action when you delete a value from the cell)
- Added a function `getPointSegments` that does the filtering
- Removed the `setDataValid_` function as it made your code less readable, and in my opinion, wasn't worthy of being its own function

  ```
  function onEdit(event) {
    var eventSheet = event.range.getSheet();
    var eventCell = event.range;
    var eventColumn = eventCell.getColumn();
    var eventValue = eventCell.getValue();
    if (eventColumn == 3 && eventSheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && eventValue != "") {
      var pointRange = eventSheet.getRange(eventCell.getRow(), eventColumn + 1);
      var pointSegments = getPointSegments_(eventSheet, eventValue);
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(pointSegments, true).build();
      pointRange.setDataValidation(rule);
    }
  }

  function getPointSegments_(sheet, selectedStreet) {
    var streetsAndPoints = sheet.getRange("A2:B").getValues();
    var pointSegments = [];
    for (var i=0; i<streetsAndPoints.length; i++) {
      var street = streetsAndPoints[i][0];
      var pointSegment = streetsAndPoints[i][1];
      if (street === selectedStreet)
        pointSegments.push(pointSegment);
    }
    return pointSegments;
  }
  ```

Lastly, be sure that your data validations in the Street field look like this (and I would actually suggest "Reject input" on invalid data).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help with this. However I'm getting a TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code").

Comment: @RafaelArevalo Are you running the code by clicking the "run" button? If so, you'll get an error, because `event` is only defined when you edit the cell. So you can test it either by (1) editing the cell that has the street or (2) modifying the code to _temporarily_ not rely on `event`.

Comment: Ahh my bad, sorry for my ignorance. It's working now. Thank you every so much for your time and the explanation!